# How to get CMake to install PDB files for targets

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

How do I get CMake to install the companion PDB files needed to debug Visual Studio generated DLL files and EXE files?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I have struggled for a while trying to get a good answer to this question. I now think I have found one: use an install file command with the `$<TARGET_PDB_FILE:tgt>` generator expression (available in CMake 3.1.3 and newer). Specifically, the install command below seems to work.  The command will copy the target ${PROJECT_NAME} pdb file to the target's installation bin directory.

```
install(FILES $<TARGET_PDB_FILE:${PROJECT_NAME}> DESTINATION bin OPTIONAL)
```

The command will install the pdb file for each configuration that generates a pdb file. By using `OPTIONAL` the install command will not generate an error if the source pdb file does not exist. This command is meant to be used for targets created with `add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ...)` or `add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ...)` commands.

This is the best answer I have found. Please let me know if there is a better one. I found some difficult to understand documentation of the `TARGET_PDB_FILE` generator experession at the "Informational Expressions" section of the [cmake-generator-expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#informational-expressions) documentation.

Comment: This only works with linker generated .pdbs , and so don't works with STATIC libraries according to the docs.
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/prop_tgt/PDB_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html#prop_tgt:PDB_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY

Comment: @Noki, you are right. This answer only works for shared libraries. Have you found a way for static libraries?

Comment: @Ali  For static libraries you can use Compile Pdbs. You should use target properties, COMPILE_PDB_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY and COMPILE_PDB_NAME, personnally I use library output directory, and library name because it's better to access in install method. 

And then I use 
install(FILES "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${Name}>/${Name}.pdb" DESTINATION "lib/static/$<CONFIG>/${Name}" OPTIONAL)
but the choice is all yours.

Doc Ref : https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/prop_tgt/COMPILE_PDB_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html#prop_tgt:COMPILE_PDB_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY

Comment: It may worth mentioning that it is possible to control build types for which the files are installed: `install(FILES $<TARGET_PDB_FILE:${PROJECT_NAME}> CONFIGURATIONS "RelWithDebInfo" DESTINATION bin)`

Comment: Can we pass this info through command line argument? Because don't want to modify existing cmakefile.