# How to remove build path from PDB-file

Tags: .net, debugging, visual-studio-2013, pdb-files

Is there a way to replace the build path that is being generated into pdb-Files?

So that e.g. an error in the form of "exception in f:\xy\build-dir\foo.vb at line 123" is then given as "exception in ***something else***\foo.vb at line 123"

Comment: [Same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952/how-do-i-change-the-locations-of-source-files-in-a-symbols-file-pdb), but it was >7 years ago now, so there might be different answers.

Comment: Any why the downvote?

Comment: No idea - wasn't from me!  It's something I'm interested in finding out if there's an answer to - wouldn't mind implementing it here

Comment: @JamesThorpe Sorry, James, my comment wasn't aimed at you, but rather at the not-so-talkative-downvoter... I appreciate your comments and also the link to the other question.

Comment: No worries - I didn't think it was, but since I got notified of your comment I thought I'd respond :)  I think unless this is edited or has a bounty placed on it, it's unlikely to get many more eyes on it unfortunately

Comment: I'm still looking for such a tool, too. Still didn't find one. I guess we need to write our own.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Hi Thomas, let me know if you found a solution, ok? Danke ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to set up a source indexing process as mentioned in [1], [2] or [3].
I'm in the process of doing this but I'm struggling myself, mainly trying to
understand how to add the correct formatted lines to the script.

[1] - https://gist.github.com/baldurk/c6feb31b0305125c6d1a
[2] - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/source-server-and-source-indexing?redirectedfrom=MSDN
[3] - https://www.codeproject.com/articles/115125/source-indexing-and-symbol-servers-a-guide-to-easi